# Rails: Rabl template with inheritance model structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, inheritance, rabl, inherited-resources

I am working on a project which uses some  inheritance structure ... The base class is ..

```
# /app/models/shape.rb
class Shape < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_superclass # https://github.com/mhuggins/multiple_table_inheritance
end
```

A subclass is ...

```
# /app/models/circle.rb
class Circle < ActiveRecord::Base
  inherits_from :shape
end
```

Here is a graphic showing the inheritance structure.

[image: Class model]

For these models I am trying to create an API using the [RABL gem](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). Here are the relevant controllers ...

```
# /app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb
class Api::V1::BaseController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
  respond_to :json, except: [:new, :edit]
end
```

...

```
# /app/controllers/api/v1/shapes_controller.rb
class Api::V1::ShapesController < Api::V1::BaseController
  actions :index
  end
end
```

...

```
# /app/controllers/api/v1/circles_controller.rb
class Api::V1::CirclesController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    @circles = Circle.all
  end
  def show
    @circle = Circle.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I created a `show` template as suggested in [Railscast #322 of Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl). It looks like this ...

```
# /app/views/circles/show.json.rabl
object @circle
attributes :id
```

When I request a circle via `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/circles/1.json` the following error message is shown ...

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template api/v1/circles/show, api/v1/base/show,
>   inherited_resources/base/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :haml, :rabl]}.

How do I need to setup the templates in order to work with the inherited resources?

---

## Partial success

I came up with the following views. I also managed to implement the inheritance structure of the models to keep the code DRY.

```
# views/api/v1/shapes/index.json.rabl
collection @shapes
extends "api/v1/shapes/show"
```

...

```
# views/api/v1/shapes/show.json.rabl
object @place
attributes :id, :area, :circumference
```

...

```
# views/api/v1/circles/index.json.rabl
collection @circles
extends "api/v1/circles/show"
```

...

```
# views/api/v1/circles/show.json.rabl
object @circle
extends "api/v1/shapes/show"
attributes :radius
if action_name == "show"
  attributes :shapes
end
```

This outputs the desired JSON for the circles (`index` action):

```
# http://localhost:3000/api/v1/cirles.json
[
 {
   "id" : 1,
   "area" : 20,
   "circumference" : 13,
   "radius" : 6
 },
 {
   "id" : 2,
   "area" : 10,
   "circumference" : 4,
   "radius: 3
 }
]
```

But it does **not** output the associated `shapes` with all attributes for some reason ...
Note: There is a association on the `Shape` model which I did not mention before.

```
# http://localhost:3000/api/v1/cirles/1.json
{
  "id" : 1,
  "area" : 20,
  "circumference" : 13,
  "radius" : 6,
  "shapes" : [
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "created_at" : "2013-02-09T12:50:33Z",
      "updated_at" : "2013-02-09T12:50:33Z"
    }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the data you provided, you put the templates in `/app/views/circles`.  The error is telling you that you need to put them in `/app/views/api/v1/circles` instead I believe.

For the second question, it sounds like you are saying each circle has_many associated shapes.  In that case, I believe something like the following should give what you want for `views/api/v1/circles/show.json.rabl`:

```
# views/api/v1/circles/show.json.rabl
object @circle
extends 'api/v1/shapes/show'
attributes :radius
child(:shapes) do
  extends 'api/v1/shapes/show'
end
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I did not see that. I will check.

Comment: Thank you for the major solution. Could you please risk an eye on a detail problem I tried to describe?

Comment: Your `views/api/v1/circles/show.json.rabl` template has in `if action_name == "show"` in it which I believe will prevent the shapes attributes from being displayed in the index action.